# Balanced work load distribution?

Tags: c, algorithm, distribution

I have N jobs with varied work loads that is to be distributed among n persons so that the work load is as balanced as possible.

e.g-we have to divide 5 jobs with work loads `<1,2,3,4,5>` between 3 persons. The best way would obviously be to distribute as follows:-

```
<1,4>,<2,3>,<5>.
```

Thus the problem is to minimize

```
z=abs(a-b)+abs(b-c)+abs(c-a)
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` are the workloads of the three persons.What would be the most efficient way to solve the problem?

Comment: Finding the optimal solution is NP-complete, [even with n = 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). So you probably want to go for some kind of approximation.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *insort(int *var, int elem)
{   // insert elem into sorted variable array var[1..n] (*var holds n)
    int n = var ? *var : 0;
    var = realloc(var, (1 + ++n) * sizeof *var);
    if (!var) exit(1);
    *var = n;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) if (elem < var[i]) break;
    memmove(var+i+1, var+i, (n-i) * sizeof *var);
    var[i] = elem;
    return var;
}

main()
{   // distribute jobs characterized by workloads among n persons
    int n, i, j, *jobs = NULL;
    printf("number of persons? "); scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("job workloads? ");
    while (scanf("%d", &i) > 0) jobs = insort(jobs, i);
    int *w, *work[n], load[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) work[i] = NULL, load[i] = 0;
    if (n > 0 && jobs) do
    {   // assign the most strenuous job to the least busy person
        w = insort(work[0], j = jobs[(*jobs)--]);
        j += load[0];
        for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) if (load[i] > j) break;
        memmove(load, load+1, --i * sizeof *load), load[i] = j;
        memmove(work, work+1,   i * sizeof *work), work[i] = w;
    } while (*jobs);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i, puts(""))
        if (w = work[i]) do printf(" %d", w[(*w)--]); while (*w);
}
```

sample run:

```
number of persons? 3
job workloads? 1 2 3 4 5.
 5
 3 2
 4 1
```